# How to create picture/diagram from text?

Tags: graphics, diagram, graphviz

I'm trying to create a number of diagrams to be published online on my web site, as PNG images. I don't want to use any image editor like Photoshop or similar. Instead, I'd like to use some plaintext format and a compiler. The only tool I know so far is Graphviz/DOT, which has certain drawbacks. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 10):

Not knowing what specific kind of diagrams you would like to create, and which drawbacks of graphviz make you look for an alternative, I'm not sure whether the following alternatives apply to your needs:

**[Web sequence diagrams](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/)** creates diagrams from text files, and there is an API available. You may also buy a server edition to be hosted in your internal network if that is a requirement.

**[yUML](http://yuml.me/)** also creates diagrams from text, and there is also a license for local use available.

Another tool for block/sequence/activity/network diagrams based on python is **[blockdiag](http://blockdiag.com/en/)**.

Comment: thanks, good links, although they provide really limited functionality, I up-voted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also on the hunt for DSL -> diagram alternatives.

My list so far:

- Graphviz (as mentioned)
- [ePiX](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/ePiX.html)
- [PGF/Tikz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) (and other LaTeX based graphics packages)
- A number of JavaScript options like

  - [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)
  - [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)

The JavaScript won't produce PNG files. But it's on the web ;-)

Comment: PGF/TikZ will generate stand alone images if you use either the standalone package or alternatively the externalization library of tikz/pgf (in the manual). The output (either ps or pdf) is then easily converted to png/jpg/...

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/, which is very help usefull for UML sketch and has been integrated with CKeditor, TiddlyWiki, TinyMCE Editor.

Answer (score 1):

A quite generic solution would be to write SVG images and feed them to a rasterizer (e.g. [rsvg](http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: I know about Graphviz, it is mentioned in the question. What are the alternatives? -1 is from me.

Comment: @yegor256: I mentioned SVG+rasterizer (e.g. rsvg) as an alternative.

Comment: @Egar please remove the graphviz from the answer, I will remove the downvote (technically can't do it otherwise)